# What does connection.connect() do in node-mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

What does the connection.connect() do in `node-mysql` library?

My code looks like this

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'ap-cdbr-azure-east-a.cloudapp.net',
  user     : '<user>',
  password : '<password>',
  database : '<database>',
});
connection.connect();
```

Later I run the query.

Even if I remove `connection.connect()` the code works as is. Some examples have it, some don't. What is the specific purpose for connect() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to establish a connection is this:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret',
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
});
```

However, a connection can also be implicitly established by invoking a query:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(...);

connection.query('SELECT 1', function(err, rows) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
});
```

Depending on how you like to handle your errors, either method may be appropriate. Any type of connection error (handshake or network) is considered a fatal error.

Courtesy: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql